# Can Peewee use highlight(), which is SQLite's FTS5 (full text search) auxiliary function?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, full-text-search, peewee

1. SQLite's FTS5 supports `highlight()`. That auxiliary function returns tags for results from full text search queries: see the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#_auxiliary_functions_).
2. Peewee's [code on Github, in the *<sqlite_ext.py>* module](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/177f04cbce02851b0420e2002a72fa91ea9b309b/playhouse/sqlite_ext.py) also mentions `highlight()`, although in passing.

   > Built-in auxiliary functions:
   >
   > - bm25(tbl[, weight_0, ... weight_n])
   > - **highlight(tbl, col_idx, prefix, suffix)**
   > - snippet(tbl, col_idx, prefix, suffix, ?, max_tokens)
3. I've found no example code or reference in Peewee's documentation to `highlight()`, even though Peewee already has support for `bm25()` and `rank()` as present FTS5 auxiliary functions.
4. Unless I've missed something, how do I use FTS5 `highlight()` with Peewee in my Python code? (I'm using Django, if that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just select `fn.highlight(...)` within a full-text search query.

```
class Post(FTS5Model):
    title = SearchField()
    content = SearchField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([Post])

Post.create(title='alpha', content='this is post alpha')
Post.create(title='beta', content='this is post beta')
Post.create(title='delta', content='this is post delta')

query = (Post
         .select(fn.highlight(Post._meta.entity, 1, '[', ']').alias('hi'))
         .where(Post.match('post')))
print(query.sql())
for row in query:
    print(row.hi)
```

Note that we have to use `Post._meta.entity` as the first argument, to avoid using the table's alias - Sqlite is particular about using the FTS table name explicitly.

Prints:

```
this is [post] alpha
this is [post] beta
this is [post] delta
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's not very evident to me where `fn.highlight()` goes in a statement. i.e. Is it within the `.where()` clause, or do you wrap it around a search phrase/query? Could you edit your answer to provide examples?

Comment: Done, no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your hard work, Peewee is an amazing ORM.

Comment: This commit adds highlight() method to SearchField. Thanks for your interest in peewee: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/6614f9ddb8bbf4d5ab6adaa4d5f8b95236b2a6f6

Comment: Thank you! Peewee's SQLite support/implementation is much better than Django's at the moment, this adds to it.